# Show that if an ideal is free as a module then it is principal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Here $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $A$.
Show that $\mathfrak a$ is principal if it is free as an $A$-module.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**: The key is to show that an ideal which is free as an $A$-module is free of rank at most $1$.  To see this it is enough to show that no ideal of $A$ contains two $A$-linearly independent elements.